# Adding an external url in a get_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to add an external url to my get_post_meta

```
<td><?php  echo get_post_meta($postID, "policy_port", true); ?></td>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Can u make your question more clear.

Comment: figured it out @Sandra                                                                                        `<td><a href = "http://somewebsite.com" target = "_blank"><?php  echo get_post_meta($postID, "policy_port", true); ?></a></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out @Sandra `<td><a href = "http://somewebsite.com" target = "_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($postID, "policy_port", true); ?></a></td>`